# How can I get how much a div is horizontally scrolled jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have a div with this configurations:

```
<div class="divImagem" style="position:relative; width: 1424px; height: 790px; overflow:hidden;">
```

Since the div is  pretty large, it is not completely shown in the browser screen. So it creates a horizontal scroll bar for this unique div (not for the whole screen page).

How can I get how much of the div has scrolled to the left? I have tried this:

```
$("div.divImagem").scrollLeft();
```

But it does not work.. it always return me 0, even if the div is horizontally scrolled.

Comment: If the overflow is hidden, how can you possibly scroll it? Are you sure you shouldn't be checking the body for the scroll properties instead ?

Comment: i just wanna to scroll this specific div.. i don't wanna to scroll the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the window that you're scrolling, not the div.

Here's an interactive example: http://jsfiddle.net/pjWt7/1/

HTML

```
<p>Scrolled: <span>0</span>px</p>
<div class="divImagem" style="position:relative; width: 1424px; height: 790px; overflow:hidden;">
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log("scrolling");
    var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    $("span").html(scrollLeft);

})
```

Comment: it doesn't work since what i'm trying to scroll is the div.. not the window

Comment: There's nothing inside the div though, so how can you scroll the div? You only scroll an overflowed element. Which in your case in the window.

Comment: i'm sorry, i haven't wrote the whole code, but I do have other elements inside this div and it creates the horizontal scrollbar in the div

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or post a link so we can better understand?

Comment: i tried to create a fiddle but it is not having the same behavior as mu project..